# Where could I find the code of "sched_getcpu()"

Tags: linux, header-files, scheduling, cpu-usage, scheduler

Recently I'm using the function `sched_getcpu()` from the header file `sched.h` on Linux.

However, I'm wondering where could I find the source code of this function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under Linux, the `sched_getcpu()` function is a glibc wrapper to `sys_getcpu()` system call, which is architecture specific.

For the x86_64 architecture, it is defined under `arch/x86/include/asm/vgtod.h` as `__getcpu()` (tree 4.x):

```
#ifdef CONFIG_X86_64

#define VGETCPU_CPU_MASK 0xfff

static inline unsigned int __getcpu(void)
{
        unsigned int p;

        /*
         * Load per CPU data from GDT.  LSL is faster than RDTSCP and
         * works on all CPUs.  This is volatile so that it orders
         * correctly wrt barrier() and to keep gcc from cleverly
         * hoisting it out of the calling function.
         */
        asm volatile ("lsl %1,%0" : "=r" (p) : "r" (__PER_CPU_SEG));

        return p;
}

#endif /* CONFIG_X86_64 */
```

Being this function called by `__vdso_getcpu()` declared in `arch/entry/vdso/vgetcpu.c`:

```
notrace long
__vdso_getcpu(unsigned *cpu, unsigned *node, struct getcpu_cache *unused)
{
        unsigned int p;

        p = __getcpu();

        if (cpu)
                *cpu = p & VGETCPU_CPU_MASK;
        if (node)
                *node = p >> 12;
        return 0;
}
```

(See [vDSO](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html) for details regarding what `vdso` prefix is).

**EDIT 1:** (in reply to arm code location)

**ARM code location**

It can be found in the `arch/arm/include/asm/thread_info.h` file:

```
static inline struct thread_info *current_thread_info(void)
{
        return (struct thread_info *)
                (current_stack_pointer & ~(THREAD_SIZE - 1));
}
```

This function is used by `raw_smp_processor_id()` that is defined in the file `arch/arm/include/asm/smp.h` as:

```
#define raw_smp_processor_id() (current_thread_info()->cpu)
```

And it's called by `getcpu` system call declared in the file `kernel/sys.c`:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(getcpu, unsigned __user *, cpup, unsigned __user *, nodep, struct getcpu_cache __user *, unused)
{
        int err = 0;
        int cpu = raw_smp_processor_id();

        if (cpup)
                err |= put_user(cpu, cpup);
        if (nodep)
                err |= put_user(cpu_to_node(cpu), nodep);
        return err ? -EFAULT : 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the replying. Actually I'm working on ARM arch. I just searched the folder arch/arm64 and I only got a file named 'unistd32.h' which included the sys_getcpu. However, there is still no details like your x86 example. Do you have any idea about where is this function of ARM? Thank you again for replying and hope you have a great weekend!

Comment: @S.Wan Now complete and accurate. Let me know if you need further details.

Comment: that's a very detailed answer for me. However, I have another related question about the getcpu. Now I want to deploy a function like sched_getcpu but I don't want to use the system call or include the header file like 'sched.h', is there any way to achieve this? I know for x86 there is an instruction called 'CPUID' but I'm new to the ARM part, thank you!

Comment: You can reuse the code from `current_thread_info()` / `raw_smp_processor_id()`.